# target in php when i click on the submit button i want to go to two different URL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

I am facing problem in a project: When I press submit, I want to go to two different urls: one from blank and one direct here.

How can I resolve this problem?

My code:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="form" target="_blank"> 

function addAmount($invoice_number,$particular,$quantity,$rate,$percentile,$amount){
    $addAmm=$this->conn->prepare("insert into `amount`(invoice_number,particular,quantity,rate,tax,amount)values(?,?,?,?,?,?);");
    $addAmm->bind_param("isssss",$invoice_number,$particular,$quantity,$rate,$percentile,$amount);
    $addAmm->execute();
    header('loaction:add_info_success.php');
    //header('loaction:printpdf.php'); error face
}
```

I want to print pdf and swith current page to iformation page.

Comment: use `onClick` attribute

Comment: You have misspelled "Location:" in the above code

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, you can't set two different `Location` headers (you have a typo in your code by the way). If you need to achieve something similar to what you want, you have to handle form by JavaScript and open two different windows with `window.open` ([manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)).

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to open multiple URL's if you combine PHP with js. But i am not sure if it's a good way to implement it. It can lead to confusion at the user. My suggestion is to add a direct download link at the success page. But if you want to go this way, you can use the next in PHP.

```
<?php
$urls = 'window.open("add_info_success.php");window.open("printpdf.php");';
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function openURLs() {
    <?php echo $urls; ?>
    }
    window.onload = openURLs;
</script>
```

If you have more URLs, you can simply use a loop and add each url's in the `windows.open()` method.

Comment: one url want to open on current tab and one on another tab

Comment: i am not sure if i understood your comment well. If you want to open a link in a new window/tab (it depends of the user's browser settings...), you can add a `_blank` like `window.open('add_info_success.php','_blank');`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
header('location:printpdf.php');
```

inside 'add_info_success.php'